# Correct way to change a field in a class when in that class?

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter

So I recently learned how to use classes and I am unsure about what is the best way to change a field in a class while in that class?

What I mean is I know that when I'm changing it in another class, I would do something like example.setX(0) to change the X value in that class since it is a private variable. But what is the better way to change the value using the code inside that class, should I just do x = 0, or setX(0), or this.setX(0)? What is the more recognized way of doing this?

Comment: There is no 'Correct way' but each way has its pros and cons (see answers)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Use of getter-setter within class](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4767352/617996)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to avoid the overhaead of calling the setter and you are sure there will 'never' be more in the setter than the assignment, it is ok to call

```
x = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.setX(0)
```

ensures additional logic required (if you set x, to you need to check y?) for changing variable is included. And `this` makes it clear the variable is in this.

Comment: If you're in the class already, encapsulation isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a private global variable x in your class, you could just do

```
x = 0; //If you don't have another variable x defined for the method, if you do use

this.x = 0;
```

Comment: There is no such thing as global variables in Java. Probably you meant instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set it via setter, just write x = 0; you need getters and setters to reach variables from other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Typical way is to use normal assignment in Your class:

```
x = 5;
```

And use getters/ setters outside class.

```
object.setX(5);
```